# What is the best way to organize SQLite sync log between local and file server's copy?

Tags: json, sqlite, synchronization, cloud

I have a document, which is SQLite DB, stored locally. Need the way to organize some Cloud service, to sync all changes made to document, incrementally. Idea is to store log of transactions in JSON format and in certain moment (manually or by time) upload this log file to Cloud server, where changes will be applied to server copy. Cloud server should be as simple as possible, not true SQL server, like MySQL etc. Are there any pitfalls with this approach?

Comment: If it's small, why don't you simply overwrite the SQLite file every time? If it's big, you probably don't want to continue using SQLite anymore.

Comment: It should be kind of S3 server, with two side synchronization. And SQLite was chosen for document format.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Your question is a little bit too broad and I can't quite understand what is it that your are asking. Could you please rephrase it? Are your [seeking recommendation for an off-site resource](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134/where-can-i-ask-about-finding-a-tool-library-or-favorite-off-site-resource)?

Comment: I found following external solution [LiteSync](http://litesync.io) But it's not open source